# why do we want to build the same project more than one build machine at a time?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Getting confused about this setting. How can it make sense when there is more than one concurrent builds for a single project.

[image]

Comment: Did you refer to the documentation? You can mouse over the `(i)` icon and get a link that thoroughly explains the scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it uses for release now, in general, the release is used to deploy (There is the same setting in build, but do not work).

Secondly, the tasks are the same, but the variables’ value can be different, also some tasks can be run or not per to different agents through [task conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/conditions).

For example:

1. Add PowerShell task to release definition

Script to set variable value per to agent name

```
param(
[string]$a
)
 Write-Host $a
if($s -eq "XXX"){
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=webname]devWeb"
}
else
{
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=webname]ReleaseWeb"
}
```

Arguments: `-a $(Agent.Name)`

[Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)

2. Then the following tasks can use this variable (webname) with different value.

Comment: So that means i could create the debug and release versions of the build at the same time. That can be handy. Any other use cases ?

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin Regarding multiple configurations, you can choose Multi-configuration option/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to the execution plan of the build phase.

> The manner in which run is parallelized.
>
> None: Tasks will run on a single agent.
>
> Multi-configuration: Run the same set of tasks on multiple
>   configurations as specified in the multipliers. Configurations will
>   run in parallel and each configuration will use a single agent. Total
>   number of agents used by the phase will depend on the number of
>   configurations, and can be limited by specifying the maximum number of
>   agents.
>
> Multi-agent: Run the same set of tasks on multiple agents, using the
>   exact number of agents specified.

[More information](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/phases#parallelexec)

The setting is not about the build, but the phase (tasks in the phase). You can do the same phase multiple times in parallel to improve build time. Of course you need a task/phase that is suitable for this.